# How to access Apache environmental variables cross-request from PHP?

Tags: php, apache, environment

What I want is a login wrapper around the entire webroot on a server running Apache 2.4 and PHP 8.2. This wrapper is only to be triggered when the client IP address is an outdoor address (i.e. other than indoor IPs like 10.0.0.0/8 or 192.168.0.0/16).
So far so good, that can I handle in Apache in .htaccess.
But when this is the case, all pages, regardless any, of the webserver should redirect to the login page when not logged in.

```
RewriteEngine  on
# No indoor addresses
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !(^\:\:1|127\.0|192\.168\.0\.0|10\.0)
# All webpages on this server
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*$ [NC]
# Cookie with name $(THECOOKIENAME) should not be set (this is the line I ask about)
RewriteCond expr "%{HTTP_COOKIE} -strcmatch '!*%{ENV:THECOOKIENAME}'"
# When all conditions met, go to login page
RewriteRule $ /loginpage.php [L]
```

So Apache checks whether a cookie is set with the name set in an envrironment variable $(THECOOKIENAME), which is to be set in a PHP script with a unique hexstring per session. I cannot use constants obviously because then setting the fixed cookie name simply allows login without credentials.

PHP code in loginpage.php::

```
if ($cookiename = auth_login()) { // check for login and generate unique key
    apache_setenv($cookiename, 1);   
    header("Location: " .$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]); exit;
} else {
    apache_setenv($cookiename, "");   
    echo showloginprompt();
}
```

Now the problem is that the env variable set by `apache_setenv()` is not recognized in Apache. I tried with a fixed $cookiename but even then it does not recognize the environmental variable.
I tried `putenv($hexstring, 1)` or even `$_ENV['THECOOKIENAME'] = $hexstring;` but to no avail as well.
It appears these functions only works in a single request. AFAIK, the `$_SESSION` would be nice, but it is not available under Apache (httpd.conf or .htaccess).

Does somebody know how to pass variables cross request between PHP and Apache ?

Comment: Consider using an auto_prepend_file instead.

Comment: Have you tried `apache_setenv($cookiename, 1, true)` or `putenv("$cookiename=1")`?

Comment: `auto_prepend_file` in .htaccess did work, but when I am logged on I set ` ini_set("auto_prepend_file",NULL);` in the auto prepend php file I thought the redirect would be disabled when I do a redirect to the original file: `header("Location: " .$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]); exit;` . But still it keeps a redirect loop.

Comment: When you're logged in, store that information in the session. Only redirect to the login page when three conditions are met: 1) You are not already on the login page 2) The IP is external 3) The session doesn't say you are already authenticated